# Google Tag Manager: gtm.dom and gtm.load are missing

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I'm implementing the Google Tag Manager script on a clients website.

I'm encountering a random issue: the dataLayer doesn't get its gtm.dom and gtm.load objects. 
It only has two Objects, one with a bunch of variables which I'm passing and a dataLoaded event which I'm pushing in.

The issue does appear randomly on different pages, sometimes the dataLayer is correctly filled, sometimes not.

What could be a reason for not getting those two gtm objects?

(note: I'm the one who implements the javascript. The GTM configuration is done by an external contractor)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution here:
https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!searchin/tag-manager/gtm.load/tag-manager/0Lpevpf2Fss/OMJFuaM04BsJ

I didnt push my variables but assigned them to dataLayer. Its overwritten, so the gtm objects are missing.

Answer (score -1):

The best implementation is assign (not push) variables before tag manager call script.

If you want to use `dataLayer.push` method, firstly load google tag manager script on the page and
 call `dataLayer.push` in javascript timeout.

Comment: You're right. The assignment of variables _after_ tag manager was initialized was the cause of my problem. I'd recommend pushing for that.

Comment: To make it simple, never assign, even before loading the GTM script. Always use dataLayer.push(), it's a good habit, it will work in every situations, and there is no need to have variations.